# How to fix 'Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x1c'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-9.0-pie

My mobile application was working fine on Android 5.1 (API 22). After upgrading to Android 9.0 Pie (Andoid 28), I can build my APK (build sucessful) but when lauching the application on my mobile, it crashes after accessing to authentication screen. The problem seems to be related to a convertion : 'value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x1c' after launching the MenuDrawer class to show on the screen a google Map.The error occurs in the getLayoutDimension method of the 'TypedArray' class when trying to convert an array.

I tried to update the build tools version in the gradle and tested with another mobile but same issue.

What was tried :

- Launching With another mobile (same issue)
- Update the gradle (projet and mobile)
- debugging

Showing graddle mobile :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    //compileSdkVersion 22
    compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ant.h2h.feelsafe"
        minSdkVersion 21
        // net.simonvt needs android.util.floatmath which has been removed since API 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 16
        versionName "3.15"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("h2h-feelsafe-free.keystore")
            storePassword "feelsafe!"
            keyAlias "h2h_free"
            keyPassword "feelsafe!"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
    // reduce apk size by not loading libraries translation and resources we do not even support in
    // our app.
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en", "de", "fr", "it"
    }
    splits {
        density {
            enable true
            exclude "tvdpi", "xxxhdpi"
            compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large'
        }

        // TODO: use something up to date (see Referent.java)
        //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    // Local binary dependencies
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        wearApp project(':wear')
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
        implementation 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.3.52@aar'
        implementation 'net.simonvt.menudrawer:menudrawer:3.0.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// Remote binary dependencies
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Tough one, I'd recommend creating a new app, add a nav drawer and run it, keep adding to that app bit by bit till you reproduce the crash

Comment: It's important to share the stack trace error as well as much code information you can, because it's quite difficult to have an insight based only on the app's build.gradle code you just shared

Comment: Check your dimen.xml in 'values' folder and see if it has all values from other dimen files in other values-xx folders

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this problem is from the menu drawer library you are using. I looked at their issues page and there is an open issue with several people experiencing the same error.

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/issues/270

I also checked your image-chooser library and their issues page doesn't have any references to this error.

Also, your gradle file has following line:

> // net.simonvt needs android.util.floatmath which has been removed since API 23.

This is referring to your menudrawer library.
I don't know if this is intentional or from a pasted snippet but you should look into this as well. If you set targetsdk higher than 23 then your libraries can't use removed apis.

**Tip For Everyone**: If your code breaks after updating sdk version and you can't find any problems in your code, check to see if the libraries you use are compatible with newer versions. And Don't forget to check Issues page on github.

Comment: Thanks all for your messages and advices. I checked already my gradle and dimension.xml. It seems ok. I will folllow the advice of Blundell recreating a new project and go step by step. Will let you know.